# How to make status bar not to disappear in MPMoviePlayerController in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, statusbar

In MPMoviePlayerController, when ever the controls disappear, even the status bar is disappearing with it. Since i want the status bar to appear even when the control disappears, i placed the below code

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];`
But the above code is not making any difference, teh status bar is getting disappeared along with the player controls. How to solve this problem.

Please find the code below, and let me know how to rectify it.

```
- (void) readyPlayer {

 mp =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
 if ([mp respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
    {
        // Set movie player layout
        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
        [mp setFullscreen:YES];

    // May help to reduce latency
    [mp prepareToPlay];

    // Register that the load state changed (movie is ready)
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
       } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
       }
    // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing. 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
}

- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSLog(@"moviePlayerLoadStateChanged");
    // Unless state is unknown, start playback
    if ([mp loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
      {
  // Remove observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                object:nil];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

      // Rotate the view for landscape playback
     [[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1000)];

      // Set frame of movieplayer
       [[mp view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1000)];

    // Add movie player as subview
    [[self view] addSubview:[mp view]];   

    // Play the movie
    [mp play];
   }
}

- (void) moviePreloadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
    // Remove observer
    NSLog(@"moviePreloadDidFinish");
    [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:nil   
                                                     name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification 
                                                   object:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    // Play the movie
    [mp play];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {    
    NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    // Remove observer
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                            object:nil];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to have the status bar there?

Comment: i ve embeded player in my app and since i'm not playing video with full screen player, i need to show the status bar on top.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known issue of `MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen`. Simply use the `MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded` controlStyle and you are good to go.

And, by the way, that is the more adequate `controlStyle` for embedded usage anyways.